# Update a jQuery script dynamic

Tags: jquery, html

Can a url param to be inserted into a jquery code?

Answer (score 0):

use `document.URL`:
For intance

```
document.URL+"?par1=par1&par2=par2"
```

Comment: the url param is dynamic is not all the time the same.

Answer (score 0):

$(location).attr('protocol') gives you the "http:" part of the url , and similarly , $(location).attr('host') will give you the host domain. for eg , on this site it would be www.stackoverflow.com. or $(location).attr('pathname') would give you the entire path , i think. you can use and concatenate the parts you want. well i dunno if this helps !